# Tried to prove that $e$ is irrational but ended up proving it's not a real number.

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification

Assume $e=p/q$, with integers $p,q$. Then we have:
\begin{align}
&qe=p\\
&(qe)^{2i\pi}=p^{2i\pi} , \text{ since $e^{2i\pi}=1$:} \\
&q^{2i\pi}=p^{2i\pi}, \text{since the exponents are the same:} \\
&q=p
\end{align}

that would imply $e=p/q=1$. But nowhere in the "proof" uses the fact that $p,q$ are integers. If we take $p,q$ complex $e$ might not even be a number.

Where is the mistake?

Comment: your last step is wrong

Comment: Please note that $(e^2)^{2i\pi} = (e^3)^{2i\pi}$, but $e^2 \neq e^3$.

Comment: Exponentiation in the complex number is not one-to-one, and the complex logarithm is multi-valued; so you cannot go from $p^{2i\pi}=q^{2i\pi}$ to $p=q$.

Comment: Since taking the $\log$ of $p^{2i\pi} = q^{2i\pi}$ won't result in $2i\pi \ln(p) = 2i\pi \ln(q)$ implying in $p=q$, what will happen when taking the $\log?$

Comment: For real numbers $a,b$, the definition of $\exp(a+bi)$ is that it equals $e^a(\cos(b) + i \sin(b))$, where $e^a$ is the usual real exponential. From this, you can verify that the exponential is not one-to-one. The complex logarithm is what is called a “multivalued function”. For each complex number $\alpha$, there are **infinitely many** values of $\log(\alpha)$, i.e., infinitely many complex numbers $c$ such that $\exp(c)=\alpha$.

Comment: So what you have is that $p^{2i\pi} = (e^{\ln(p)})^{2i\pi} = e^{2i\pi\ln(p)} = (\cos(2\pi\ln(p))+i\sin(2\pi\ln(p))$. Similarly with $q^{2i\pi}$. So all you know is that $\cos(2\pi\ln(p))=\cos(2\pi\ln(q))$ and $\sin(2\pi\ln(p))=\sin(2\pi\ln(q))$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You went wrong in the last step. As you're fully aware, $e^{2i \pi} = 1$, just as $e^0 = 1$. This means that the complex exponential function is no longer injective, literally meaning that $e^z = e^w$ no longer implies $z = w$, with $z = 2 i \pi$ and $w = 0$ being a counterexample.

So, what does $e^z = e^w$ actually imply? We have
$$e^z = e^w \implies \frac{e^z}{e^w} = 1 \implies e^{z - w} = 1.$$

If we write $z - w = x + iy$, where $x, y \in \Bbb{R}$, this yields
$$1 = e^{x + iy} = e^x(\cos(y) + i \sin(y)),$$
which implies $e^x = 1$ from taking the modulus of both sides, and $y = 2\pi k$ for some integer $k$. Since $x \in \Bbb{R}$, we must have $x = 0$, so
$$z - w = 2 i \pi k$$
for some $k \in \Bbb{Z}$.

So, given $p^{2 i \pi} = q^{2 i \pi}$, we can conclude, by definition of complex exponentiation,
$$e^{2 i \pi \log p} = e^{2 i \pi \log q}$$
and thus, for some $k \in \Bbb{Z}$,
$$2 i \pi \log p = 2 i \pi \log q + 2 i \pi k \implies \log(p / q) = k \implies p / q = e^k.$$
In this case, $k = 1$; there is no contradiction.

Comment: This question makes an excellent false proof question for undergraduates!

Comment: Then is true that $\ln(z^w) = w \ln z + 2i\pi k$? For complexs $z,w$ and integer $k$?

Comment: @Pinteco That's a stickier question, deserving of its own separate question. It's a little bit too long to answer in a comment, but just bear in mind that, when you allow the base to be complex, [complex exponentiation is multivalued](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Complex_exponents_with_complex_bases)!

Comment: Thanks! I'll read some more about it.

Answer (score 0):

$$q^{2\pi i}=p^{2\pi i}\to e^{i\cdot 2\pi \ln q}=e^{i \cdot 2\pi \ln p}\tag{1}$$

Remember that $e^{i\theta}=\cos\theta +i\sin \theta$:

Because of the periodicity of $\cos$ and $\sin$, the *only* conclusion you can draw from $(1)$ is:

$$2\pi\ln(q)=2\pi(\ln(p)+k) : k\in \Bbb Z$$

Which we may simplify to: $$\ln(q)-\ln(p)=k\implies \frac qp = e^k$$

Here, $k=-1$ trivially.